# Goroutine prevents program from ending

Tags: go

I was going through the Go Tour, and this piece of code really melted my mind:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        // quit <- 0 // Suppose I remove this line (note that it is present in the Tour)
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Now I get a fatal error telling me all goroutines are asleep, so I'm assuming the open channel prevents the program from returning and exiting.

The question is, why does this result in an error? The program ended, there is reader for the `c` channel, and there are no more code statements to execute, so what is really happening here?

P.S If the `quit` channel never evaluated to True, does this mean the first case will keep looping forever?

Comment: The program doesn't end until `main` returns. You created a deadlock, so the runtime is telling you so.

Comment: @JimB I don't follow, what's a deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Since you never write anything to the `quit` channel, <s>your program [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) on the `select case` statement</s> your program keeps producing values and adding them to the `c` channel with no consumer.

## Explanation

The code is waiting for something to be added either to the `quit` channel. Since it is not being written to, the program keeps calculating the fibonacci sequence.

Concurrent programming is very different from 'standard', linear programming.

The line you removed would guarantee that there would be enough data in the `quit` channel to end the program, since the `fib` function only ends when that channel is read from.

```golang
for { // an infinite loop
  case c <- x:
      x, y = y, x+y
  case <-quit:
      fmt.Println("quit")
      return // your only exit is here, 
             // which is only executed when data is read from the quit channel
}
```

You are calculating values forever, with your only exit being writing to the `quit` channel; however, that never happens.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer, it clears my confusion. I have to ask though, you mentioned no data was being added to the `c` channel, even though there was data being added in the first case. Does that mean if there is no receiver, then you cannot add data to a sender?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the `for i := 0; i < 5; i++` loop. This loop reads five 'data' from the `c` channel  and ends. After that, the infinite loop on the `fibonacci` function keeps producing values and adding them to the channel. Your program isn't stuck, it just doesn't end.

Comment: Your edit is not really accurate, this is still by definition a deadlock, The stack trace even shows you exactly where the blocking operations are happening. The `fibonacci` function is blocked in the `select`, `main` is block waiting for `fibonacci` to return. If there were something still "producing" values, it would not be a deadlock, because some goroutine would be continuing to run.

Comment: @kwevelis: from the tour itself: "By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready". This is how channels can be used for synchronization between goroutines.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your response. My confusion was that - even though I know it was a deadlock (it's in the error message) - I didn't know why I was getting it. I thought that if there were no more code to execute in the `main` thread, the program will just ignore all channels and goroutines and just end. From your explanation, and from @rafadeboas's explanation, my understanding is that the `main` thread will block, waiting for a response from one of the `select` cases. Since the `select` is stuck in an infinite loop just adding values to the channels without any receivers from the other end

Comment: , the program signals a deadlock, telling me all goroutines are asleep, as in, there are no receivers on the other end of the channel. Did I get this correctly?

Comment: @kwevelis, the program signals a deadlock simply because no goroutines can proceed. It's not that you must have a receiver for the value, you just need a way to return from the blocking `fibonacci` function, like what `case <-quit:` provides.